# Pandas split column in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['2.1 text1 and bla bla 1', '2.2 text2 bla 2', '2.3 text3 other text 7']})
```

that contains in the column "Title" the following information:

```
Title
2.1 text1 and bla bla 1
2.2 text2 bla 2
2.3 text3 other text 7
```

I tried to split the column in the following manner:

```
col1     Title               col3
2.1      text1 and bla bla    1
2.2      text2 bla            2
2.3      text3 other text     7
```

I tried to follow multiple ways but without success.

Comment: `df['Title'].str.split(expand=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on white space to obtain `x`. Then take the first items of lists and assign them to `'col1'` and the last items to `'col3'`. Finally take what's left, join them back and assign them to `'Title'`:

```
x = df['Title'].str.split()
df['col1'] = x.str[0]
df['col3'] = x.str[-1]
df['Title'] = x.apply(lambda y: ' '.join(y[1:-1]))
df = df[['col1','Title','col3']]
```

Output:

```
  col1              Title col3
0  2.1  text1 and bla bla    1
1  2.2          text2 bla    2
2  2.3   text3 other text    7
```

@Neither gives a much better solution in the comments.

```
df.Title.str.split(r"^(\d\.\d)\s(.+)\s(\d)$", expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1].add_prefix("col_")
```

Comment: It seems we're dumping code without explaining it, so `df.Title.str.split(r"^(\d\.\d)\s(.+)\s(\d)$", expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1].add_prefix("col_")`